# Manual test cases run in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

Currently for Xamarin, NUnit has to be used to write scripts which runs in all the devices at the same time.

Is it possible to just upload an APK or IPA file to Xamarin Test cloud and test the application manually in each device with out writing any code?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot test the application manually with Xamarin Test Cloud as far as I am aware.

Without writing any tests you could use the [App Explorer](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/getting-started-app-explorer/). App Explorer is a utility that will tap every button and visit every screen in your app automatically in Xamarin Test Cloud.